# Does this graph already have a name?

Tags: graph-theory

I am studying the Cartesian product of such a graph with other graphs. I want to ask if it has a known name?

[image]

By the way, for some special graphs, is there a good website to check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently (according to [this website](https://www.graphclasses.org/smallgraphs.html#nodes6)) this graph is called "X84", or "g6: ElD?" (whatever that means). Some details about this nomenclature have been helpfully provided in [David Scholz's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4066709/16078).

Comment: Thank you for your help, this website is great, but the graph seem to be called "X84" not "A "according to this website. Although I wonder how he came up with the name.

Comment: argh, you're exactly right—answer corrected

Answer (score 2):

There is no well established name for this particular graph. However, there is a well known graph which is similar to some extend.

It is called the [Banner graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BannerGraph.html)

[image]

It is obtained by joining a single vertex of the cycle graph $C_4$ to a [pendant](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/PendantVertex.html) vertex. Our graph is obtained by joining two non-adjacent vertices of $C_4$ with two pendant vertices.

Some comments to the website given by Greg Martin:

The string "ElD?" is the graph6 representation of your graph. This format was specified by Brendan McKay [here](https://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/%7Ebdm/data/formats.html). It is used in most computational frameworks, such as Mathematica, SageMath, etc. Using sage, we can parse this format directly into sage graph objects as follows

```
g=Graph("ElD?")
g.show()
```

yielding to

[image]

The string "X84" is the internal name in the database [ISGCI](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/isgci.html). This can be verified using

```
t = graph_classes.smallgraphs()
```

which returns a set in which "X84" is used for internal reference only.